# Oracle Efficiently joining tables with subquery in FROM

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle10g

Table 1:

```
| account_no | **other columns**...
+------------+-----------------------
| 1          |
| 2          |
| 3          |
| 4          |
```

Table 2:

```
| account_no | TX_No | Balance | History    |
+------------+-------+---------+------------+
| 1          | 123   |  123    | 12.01.2011 |
| 1          | 234   |  2312   | 01.03.2011 |
| 3          | 232   |  212    | 19.02.2011 |
| 4          | 117   |  234    | 24.01.2011 |
```

I have multiple join query, one of the tables(Table 2) inside a query is problematic as it is a view which computes many other things, that is why each query to that table is costly. From Table 2, for each `account_no` in Table 1 I need the whole row with the greatest `TX_NO`, this is how I do it:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 A LEFT JOIN 
            ( SELECT 
                    X.ACCOUNT_NO, 
                    HISTORY, 
                    X.BALANCE 
              FROM TABLE2 X INNER JOIN 
                (SELECT 
                        ACCOUNT_NO, 
                        MAX(TX_NO) AS TX_NO 
                FROM TABLE2 
                GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NO) Y ON X.ACCOUNT_NO = Y.ACCOUNT_NO) B 
            ON B.ACCOUNT_NO = A.ACCOUNT_NO
```

As I understand at first it will make the inner join for all the rows in **Table2** and after that left join needed `account_no`'s with **Table1** which is what I would like to avoid.

My question: Is there a way to find the `max(TX_NO)` for only those accounts that are in **Table1** instead of going through all? I think it will help to increase the speed of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track, but I don't think that you need to, and would not myself, nest the subqueries the way you have done.  Instead, if you want to get each record from table 1 and the matching max record from table 2, you can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account_no ORDER BY TX_No DESC) rn
    FROM TABLE2 t
) t2
    ON t1.account_no = t2.account_no AND
       t2.rn = 1
```

If you want to continue with your original approach, this is how I would do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.account_no = t2.account_no
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT account_no, MAX(TX_No) AS max_tx_no
    FROM TABLE2
    GROUP BY account_no
) t3
    ON t2.account_no = t3.account_no AND
       t2.TX_No      = t3.max_tx_no
```

Instead of using a window function to find the greatest record per account in `TABLE2`, we use a second join to a subquery instead.  I would expect the window function approach to perform better than this double join approach, and once you get used to it can even easier to read.

Comment: ughh, yeah it looks like a great idea, should have thought about window functions, I will try

Comment: yes, It decreased the time by half, which I find great. The only thing is that by doing that window function like in your query I get `ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here` error. that is why I first made a select from another select  with `ROW_NUMBER().. as rn` as a subquery, and then used standart `where rn = 1`

Comment: @Hatik Yes you are correct, I updated my answer.  I didn't have much sample data and also it is hard to test Oracle on both SQLFiddle and Rextester.

Comment: Another thing is, I think it is necessary to add alias to  `TABLE2 ` something like `FROM TABLE2 b` and in select use `select b.*, rownumber...` p.s Don't misunderstand me, I just want the answer to be complete

Answer (score 1):

If table1 is comparatiely less expensive then you could think of doing a left outer join first which would considerable decrease the resultset and from that pick the latest transaction id records alone

```
select <required columns> from 
 (
 select f.<required_columns),row_number() over (partition by account_no order by tx_id desc ) as rn 
from 
(
  a.*,b.tx_id,b.balance,b.History
  from table1 a left outer join table2 b 
 on a.account_no=b.account_no
)f
)g where g.rn=1
```

Comment: yes, seems like a better Idea than what I've done in the question